# Json jQuery each() looping into table

Tags: jquery, json, loops, each

I have gotten to this point and can't seem to get the data into a table.

```
var report_data = [{
"report_type": "items_sold",
"customer_data": {
    "Visual Flight Guide": 25,
    "Flight Radio for Pilots VFR Operations": 17,
    "ATC Pilots Logbook": 231,
    "Aerobatics Principles and Practice": 1,         
}
}]

var table = "";
//Get Order Contents
$.each(report_data.report_type, function (i, items) {
table += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + items + "</td></tr>";
});
table += "</table>";

$('table').append(table);
```

The outcome:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Visual Flight Guide</td><td>25</td></tr>
<tr><td>Flight Radio for Pilots VFR Operations</td><td>17</td></tr>
...
</table>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong.. and code is outputting just the expected values. Check the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

You should be looping over the customer_data array, not the report_type.

```
$.each(report_data.report_type, function (i, items) {
```

Should be:

```
$.each(report_data.customer_data, function (i, items) {
```

Beyond that, the js looks like it will work. If you're still having problems after you make the suggested change, can you show us what the HTML looks like?

Comment: `$.each(report_data[0].customer_data, function (i, items) {`

Comment: Good point @RajaprabhuAravindasamy. I would suggest removing the brackets from the report_data, so that it is an object, and not an array, but this works with the code he has given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var table = "";
//Get Order Contents
$.each(report_data[0].customer_data, function (i, items) {

    console.log(i);
table += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + items + "</td></tr>";
});
table += "</table>";

$('table').append(table);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCAnL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try  this . for hole  report_data array

```
for (var k in report_data) {
    var table = "";
    $.each(report_data[k].customer_data, function (key, val) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + val + "</td></tr>";
    });
    table += "</table>";
    $('table').append(table);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eZjXc/1/)